# Nested CTEs and Subquery with aggregate calculations

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like help with some SQL code. My goal is to calculate the percent of a customers in the 01 customer group who have spent more than $350, and the percent in that group who have spent more than $1000 in 2022. The data needed to complete the request is in two tables: 1) sales_order and 2) sales_order_item.

- The order_id links the two tables.
- The customer group of interest is 01.
- Customers can have multiple orders from different dates.
- The sales_order_item table has a column named row_total which is the
  cost of an item, not the entire order's total. So one order can have
  multiple row_totals.

The table structures are below:

sales_order:

| order_id | customer_id | customer_group | order_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 | 01 | 9/1/2021 |
| 002 | 2 | 06 | 11/2/2021 |
| 003 | 3 | 03 | 1/4/2022 |
| 004 | 1 | 01 | 2/1/2022 |
| 005 | 2 | 06 | 2/3/2022 |
| 006 | 3 | 03 | 3/1/2022 |
| 007 | 1 | 01 | 2/1/2022 |
| 008 | 2 | 06 | 2/3/2022 |
| 009 | 3 | 03 | 3/1/2022 |
| 010 | 4 | 01 | 3/2/2022 |
| 011 | 5 | 01 | 3/3/2022 |
| 012 | 6 | 01 | 3/3/2022 |
| 013 | 7 | 01 | 3/4/2022 |

sales_order_item:

| order_id | row_total |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 1000.00 |
| 002 | 20.00 |
| 003 | 350.00 |
| 004 | 350.00 |
| 005 | 2000.00 |
| 006 | 3000.00 |
| 007 | 100.00 |
| 008 | 200.00 |
| 009 | 300.00 |
| 010 | 200.00 |
| 011 | 100.00 |
| 012 | 1500.00 |
| 013 | 350.00 |

I have tried the following code but keep getting an error at the customer_counts CTE:

```
with orders as (
     select
         so.order_id,
         so.customer_id as customer_id,
         soi.row_total as row_total
     from sales_order as so
     inner join sales_order_item as soi
     on so.order_id = soi.order_id
     where customer_group_id = 01 and extract(year from so.order_date) = 2022),
    
 customer_sums as (
    select 
        customer_id,
        sum(row_total)
    from orders
    group by customer_id),
    
  customer_counts as(
    (select count(customer_id)
     from customer_sums
     group by customer_id
     having sum(row_total) >350) as customers_350,
    (select count(customer_id)
     from customer_sums
     group by customer_id
     having sum(row_total) >1000) as customers_1000,
    (select count(customer_id)
     from customer_sums
     group by customer_id
     having sum(row_total) >0) as all_customers),

 select 
     all_customers,
    (customers_350/all_customers *100) as %over350, 
    (customers_1000/all_customers *100) as %over1000
 from customer_counts
```

When this query is run the error says:

> "ERROR: syntax error at or near "as" LINE 22: having sum(row_total) >350) >as customers_350"

For customer group 01 in 2022, the expected answer in this example:

2/5 (40%) of customers have spent >$350, and

1/5 (20%) have spent >$1000.

Comment: i do curious, is `customer_counts` even executable as normal sql query?

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), "5. Some Additional Suggestions" and "3. Show Your Expected Outcome"

Comment: Question has been updated with error description and expected result from example tables.

Comment: @BagusTesa, you are on to something. When running the customer counts query by itself. There was an error that said, "ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression."

Haven't been able to fix that.